# How to center an unordered list inside a fixed position div with 100% width

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web layout where I have a navigation bar at the top set as position:fixed; width: 100%; so that even when the user scrolls it stays at the top of the viewport and occupies the width of the page. I want to put a centered horizontal unordered list of links (width 940px) inside it like so:

```
<nav id='nav-bar'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Having tried various combinations of display and position/float etc I have been unable to centre it without the list wrapping over two lines if I try to resize the page. I expect there may be some other wrapper required to contain the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/JuYpT/)  http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/JuYpT/

Its only `margin:auto` and `display:inline-block` you need.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce a single row of `li` elements within the `ul` element, and to centre them:

```
#nav-bar {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

To have the `li` elements obey those rules, use *either* `inline` or `inline-block`:

```
#nav-bar li {
    display: inline-block; /* allows width and height to be set on the element ('inline' does not) */
}
```

JS Fiddles:

- [`display: inline-block;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FWtFe/)
- [`display: inline;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FWtFe/1/)

Finally, a demo showing the use of relative widths (in `%`), with a `min-width` set to prevent the `li` elements becoming *too* small: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FWtFe/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your content into `fixed` parent:

```
<div id="fixed-element">
    <nav id='nav-bar'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>​
```

and apply css to it:

```
#fixed-element{position:fixed:top:0;}
#nav-bar{position:relative;float:left;left:50%;}
#nav-bar ul{position:relative;float:right;right:50%;}
#nav-bar ul li{float:left;clear:none;display:inline-block;list-style:outside none;margin:0 5px;}​
```

[Here is the link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSxLG/1/)